# Prevent JavaScript from lowercasing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, dom

As suggested in several places on the web, I have used jQuery in my web application as a quick and dirty way for creating and manipulating XML documents. For example:

```
var doc = $("<root/>")
var foo = $("<foo/>").appendTo(doc)
var bar = $("<bar/>").appendTo(foo).text("hello")
console.log(doc.html())
```

However I just found out that tags in XML are case sensitive, whereas in HTML5 they are not. This turns out to be a big problem because my server requires some mixed case tags, however JavaScript automatically converts everything to lowercase:

```
$("<FooBar/>")
<foobar></foobar>'
```

Is there some way I can work around this, e.g. by making the top element (`doc`) an xml node? Or do I have to rewrite my entire application to use proper XML manipulation rather than DOM tools?

Comment: No this is very different. The `$.parseXML()` returns an element with a completely different API.

Comment: I coucur, but I can't change the mark.  Meanwhile, please see `jQuery.parseHTML` and note the context parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my mind.  I now think that dup is a good fit, it just don't have good enough answers.  I've added an answer that you should be able to use.